# How to transform a column string from lowercase to capital letter in a data frame using python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a string column in a data frame from lowercase letter to capital letter. I only want that specific column to be modified, not the dataframe as its whole.

```
worker           name       hours/task    Country
constructor      Marco        7           United States
operator         Samuel       6           United States
designer         Ivgnar       5           Sweden
designer         Michael      6           Britain
```

the column with name 'worker'. I want its words to be turned into capital letters.

Thanks,

Comment: `df['worker'] = df['worker'].str.upper()` ?

Comment: That's right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas str.upper would work as well.

```
df['worker'] = df['worker'].str.upper()
```